# setting color and font-size inline in HTML4?

Tags: html, css, html4

Sorry for the retro question, but I have to add two highlighted paragraphs of text (just a kind of "oldness warning") to a *VERY* old website (HTML4), and I can't seem to find out how to set text color and size as inline attributes in HTML4.

I tried all kind of attributes in the `p`and `h2` tags (like `<p color="#ff0000">`also "text, "text-color" and others, but none of them worked.

I know all this for today's standards, but this is in HTML4. Is anyone old enough to remember? ;-)

Comment: As I wrote below, I had tried the style attribute at first and it didn't work. So obviously I had some kind of typing or syntax error when trying which I oversaw, hence my question here (and yes, I googled beforehand, but HTML4 stuff is not *that* easy to find in the big haystack). Anyway, thanks to the people who answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check this out.

```
<p style="color:#ff0000; font-size:12px;">
```

you can check by reducing font site or can write like this for forcefully apply style in html element:

```
<p style="color:#ff0000; font-size:12px !important;">
```

Comment: inline CSS is not supportive for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The style attribute was introduced in HTML 4, so you can use inline CSS.

```
style="color: #ff0000"
```

There is no, and never has been, a presentation attribute specifically for setting the foreground colour of a paragraph element. That was the job of the font element.

Comment: thanks once more! I had tried the style attribute first and it didn't work, but I obviously made some kind of typing or syntax error when trying which I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways:

1. The HTML4 `font` tag.
2. The CSS `font-size` and `font-color` properties.

### 1. The HTML4 `font` tag:

```html
<p><font size="12" color="#ff0000">hello world</font></p>
```

### 2. The CSS `font-size` and `font-color` properties:

```css
p {
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<p>hello world</p>
```

---

Hope I could help